# How do I run unittest.TestCase subclasses with py.test in PyCharm?

Tags: python, pycharm

I can run files with plain `test_*` functions without any problems, however when I try to run a file with the tests contained in a subclass of `unittest.TestCase` I get the following result

```
W:\dev\Scripts\python.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 3.0.1\helpers\pycharm\pytestrunner.py" -p pytest_teamcity W:/dev/datakortet/xfr/setup/tests
Testing started at 3:31 PM ...
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform win32 -- Python 2.7.3 -- pytest-2.3.5
plugins: cov, xdist
collected 0 items / 1 skipped

========================== 1 skipped in 0.57 seconds ===========================

Process finished with exit code 0
Empty test suite.
```

when I run the same tests from the commandline:

```
(dev) w:\dev\datakortet\xfr\setup\tests>py.test test_setup_views.py
========================================================================================= test session starts ====
platform win32 -- Python 2.7.3 -- pytest-2.3.5
plugins: cov, xdist
collected 6 items

test_setup_views.py ......

====================================================================================== 6 passed in 4.15 seconds ==

(dev) w:\dev\datakortet\xfr\setup\tests>
```

do I need to add anything to the tests (I don't have a test suite, or a test runner, since py.test doesn't require this...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to your respective file, with contains `unittest` tests. Then what you need to do is Go to `Python Integrated Tools` inside of settings. Then set the Default test runner to `Unittest`.

[image]

After that, you can just go into your unittest file, you can just run it, and it will perform the tests.

Or you can right click your directory of your files where the tests are located, and right click, and you should be able to see `"Run Unittests in test.py"` or something. That will run all your tests

Comment: That works, but then I have to go into settings and change the default test runner every time I need to run a test.  What I would like to do is use py.test to run the unittest tests.  Py.test handles finding and running unittest tests fine, and it allows me to have simple tests for simple code, and use the full power of unittest when that is needed.  I can even mix the two in the same test file...

Comment: @thebjorn Thats the problem. Hopefully they'll make a better testing integration in the future, but as things stand, PyCharm just works with one testing framework at a time.

Comment: @thebjorn Again, I am deeply sorry that I cannot offer something better for you.